# How can I separate my data table based on a binary criterion (gender)?

Tags: r

I am n ew to R and I have this data set (http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/kidsfeet.dat.txt) and need to plot the width (y axis) versus length (x axis) of feet, but differentiate them between genders.

It has been read in as such:

```
kidsfeet <- read.table("http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/kidsfeet.dat.txt")
names(kidsfeet) <- c("month","year","length","width","sex","foot","hand")
```

How can I split this data set so that I have the female lengths and widths and the male lengths and widths to work with separately?

I have a feeling this is an easy answer but I'm having a hard time knowing what to search to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kidsfeet <- read.table("http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/kidsfeet.dat.txt")
names(kidsfeet) <- c("month","year","length","width","sex","foot","hand")

genderfeet <- split(kidsfeet, kidsfeet$sex)

head(genderfeet$G)
##    month year length width sex foot hand
## 8      6   88   21.0   8.8   G    L    R
## 9      5   88   21.6   9.3   G    R    R
## 15    11   87   24.0   9.3   G    L    R
## 16     4   88   21.7   7.9   G    R    R
## 17    12   87   22.0   8.7   G    R    L
## 18     3   88   22.7   8.8   G    R    R

head(genderfeet$B)
##   month year length width sex foot hand
## 1     5   88   22.4   8.4   B    L    R
## 2    10   87   23.4   8.8   B    L    L
## 3    12   87   22.5   9.7   B    R    R
## 4     1   88   23.2   9.8   B    L    R
## 5     2   88   23.1   8.9   B    L    R
## 6     3   88   23.7   9.7   B    R    R
```

Take a look at `dplyr`'s `group_by` as well, to possibly save yourself some computational effort.

Answer (score 0):

And you can plot them gender-wise:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(kidsfeet, aes(x = length, y = width)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(sex ~ .)
```